# Starcraft 2 on Macbook Pro Retina on external 27" - No valid resolution

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

[image]

My primary monitor is set to the 27" at 2560 x 1440.

I can't window and unwindow (command + m) either. what to do!?

Comment: Change the Display Mode to Windowed and select a smaller resolution.

Comment: Like I said, I can't window. Is there a way to start windowed?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out that you can just do "window full screen". Only problem is that playing liek this  is really annoying since your mouse goes outside the window, and the performance degrades. :(

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Go to `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Blizzard/StarCraft\ II/`
2. Open `Variables.txt`
3. Change `displaymode` to `displaymode=0`

Game should open in windowed mode and allows you to change it to full screen mode and choose resolution.

```
displayMode=0 (for windowed) 
displayMode=1 (for windowed fullscreen) 
displayMode=2 (fullscreen)
```

Make sure you have write access to the `Variables.txt` (You may have not due to workaround for the language package issue). By `chmod` in terminal or `cmd + I` on the keyboard.